# Pyspark cannot create a parquet table in hive

Tags: hive, pyspark, parquet

Many searches point to pyspark code to create tables in hive metastore with something like:

`hivecx.sql("...create table syntax that matches the dataframe...")
 df.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy('partition_colname').insertInto("national_dev.xh_claimline")`

I've tried many variations of write/save/insertinto and modes, but always get:

`Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /user/hive/warehouse/national_dev.db/xh_claimline/000000_0`

The table directory exists in hadoop, but the 000000_0 sub directory(s) does not.   I thought this was because the table is empty and i haven't written to it yet.

`hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/national_dev.db/xh_claimline
Found 2 items
drwxrwxrwt   - mryan hive          0 2017-03-20 12:26 /user/hive/warehouse/national_dev.db/xh_claimline/.hive-staging_hive_2017-03-20_12-26-35_382_2703713921168172595-1
drwxrwxrwt   - mryan hive          0 2017-03-20 12:29 /user/hive/warehouse/national_dev.db/xh_claimline/.hive-staging_hive_2017-03-20_12-29-40_775_73045420253990110-1`

On Cloudera, Spark version:
    17/03/20 11:45:21 INFO spark.SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.0

Answer (score 0):

Looked at insert into statement, Here data write mode `overwrite` is used, then no need to write insert in to. Directly use `saveAsTable` with `parquet` format. Here is modified statement:-

```
df = hivecx.sql("...create table syntax that matches the dataframe...")
df.write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").partitionBy('partition_colname').saveAsTable("national_dev.xh_claimline")
```

Comment: Thanks @rakesh-kumar - I tried that before, but i tried again just now to make sure.   I get the exact same result.                          `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /user/hive/warehouse/national_dev.db/xh_claimline/000000_0`

Comment: @MattRyan then i think you don't have db with name national_dev so make sure db existence through hive shell